# Hold scroll position on slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slidetoggle

I have a button that slides multiple divs in or out.  On clicking the button, I want the button to stay at the same position in the window when it is clicked, but since the sliding div changes the height above the button it ends up moving (see fiddle to see how this looks: http://jsfiddle.net/fJWeQ/3/)

I've looked at animating `scrollTop` but don't see how to use it in a way that wouldn't be jumpy.  Is there a way to anchor the scroll window to an element while the animation is taking place?

Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be missing the JavaScript. Please update and include your code in the question. Can't really help until we can see what we're working with

Comment: It's in the button onclick event since it's super-short and something wasn't working for me the normal way.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I'm not seeing any code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a step callback function to fix this, which is 1px jittery at most.  A bit of info, in case someone stumbles across this:

Some detail on how to use step callback functions is [here](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/).  A step callback function runs on each iteration of the animation.

Before the animation:

```
holdSpot = this; //can set to whatever element you want to hold it at
topOfElement = $(holdSpot).offset().top;
topOfScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
effectiveHeight = topOfElement - topOfScroll;
```

Step function (runs on each iteration of animation):

```
topOfElement = $(holdSpot).offset().top; //finds new position of element
$(window).scrollTop(topOfElement - effectiveHeight); //sets scrollTop to position of element minus the original height difference
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically change the divs the scroll will adjust also. Your intent is to keep the button fixed as you stated, so I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJWeQ/4/) to work as such.

Essentially making the button `positon:fixed` when clicked. You can of course opt to make the button fixed in your css, and not wait for a click.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit jittery, but here's a solution you might be able to build on

http://jsfiddle.net/fJWeQ/5/

While it's in motion I poll the current scroll position and make sure that the button is still in the same place.

```
var togglesInMotion = 0;
var buttonOffset;
var intervalHandler;
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $("#toggleButton").click(function(){        
        buttonOffset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();        
        intervalHandler = setInterval(function(){            

            var curOffset = $('#toggleButton').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();        
            var adjustment = curOffset - buttonOffset;

            var currentScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(window).scrollTop(currentScrollPosition + adjustment);
            //$(window).scrollTop(0);
        });        
        togglesInMotion++;
        $('#div1').slideToggle("slow", stopScrolling);  
        togglesInMotion++;
        $('#div3').slideToggle("slow", stopScrolling);                  
    });    
});
function stopScrolling(){    
    togglesInMotion--;
    if(togglesInMotion == 0){
        clearTimeout(intervalHandler);        
    }
}
```